# bash how to read contents of two files

Tags: bash

I have this script which reads lines from two files and outputs them in order of:

```
The first line of file1
the first line of file2
the second line of file1
the second line of file2
etc
```

How do I do this without using the external paste command in the script ?

```
paste -d'\n' file1 file2 | while read line1 && read line2;
do
#echo "$line1 $line2" 
echo "$line1" 
echo "$line2" 
done
```

Comment: what you want to do if one file has more lines than the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for that article Kerrek .... have updated my code which works fine now :

```
exec 5< file1
exec 6< file2
while read line1 <&5 && read line2 <&6
do
echo  "$line1"
echo "$line2"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use file descriptors and `read`, e.g. [see here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/reading-multiple-files-bash).

```
exec 5< file1
exec 6< file2

read line1 <&5
read line2 <&6

echo -n "$line1\n$line2"
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3< bash.sh
exec 4< data

while read l1 <&3 && read l2 <&4
do
    echo "$l1"
    echo "$l2"
done
```

`data`

```
1908 462
232 538
232 520
232 517
```

`./bash.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
1908 462

232 538
exec 3< bash.sh
232 520
exec 4< data
232 517
```

If you don't want to end when you reach end of the first file, use this

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3< aaa
exec 4< bbb

while true
do
    end=1
    read l <&3
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then
        echo "$l"
        end=0
    fi

    read l <&4
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then
        echo "$l"
        end=0
    fi

    if [ $end -eq 1 ];
    then
        break
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

External to the `while`, and external to some enclosing script file are two different things.  You're perfectly free to move the paste into the file, and still pipe into the `while` within.

I'm not sure if that's what you're getting after.  Is it?