# Bash read two files line per line

Tags: bash, loops

The correct syntax for what I want to do is :

> exec 5< file1
>
> exec 6< file2
>
> while read line1 <&5 && read line2 <&6
>
> do
>
> sed -i "s/value_to_modify/$line2/" /$line1/file_to_modify
>
> done

THANKS

this is the problem ; I want to read two files :
First file contains this line

```
folder1 
folder2 
folder3 
folder2
```

Second File contains this line

```
Description1
Description2
Description3
Description4
```

I want to modify a file in each folder with Description1 for the folder1, Description2 for the folder2...

Is there a way to use for loop ?

```
for line_file1 in $(cat file1)
do
    for line_file2 in $(cat file2)
      do
        sed -i "s/value/$line_file2/" /$line_file1/file_to_modify
      done
  done
```

Thanks

Olivier

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
#! /bin/bash    
while true; do
  read -r folder <&3
  if [ -z "$folder" ]; then
      break
  fi
  read -r line_file2 <&4
  sed -i "s/value/$line_file2/" /$folder/file_to_modify
done 3<fileOfFolders 4<fileOfLines
```

If the two files have differents number of line, you'll need to check that.

Comment: nice one using file descriptors, +1

Comment: Try `while read -r folder <&3; do` instead of `while true; do` (and of course, delete the next `read`.

Comment: it doesn't stop :P. I forgot the if, thanks @jaba10

Comment: It works now: +1. I leave my above comment as an alternative.

Comment: I've seen this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423684/bash-how-to-read-contents-of-two-files) it's work fine